# nginx proxy manager how set redirect 443 SSL default host to another local web server apache+nginx+LetsEncrypt

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

Path config
/nginx-proxy-manager/data/nginx/**default_host**/site.conf

1. *Internet* Client enter brouser site.com or any name (DNS A 777.777.777.777) ->
   2.*Lan* nginx proxy manager (if not found site) (WAN 777.777.777.777 LAN192.168.100.36) ->
2. Apache+nginx+ssl server(192.168.100.37)**

HTTP is work HTTPS not work**

Error on start nginx proxy manager Starting nginx ... app_1 | nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /data/nginx

## Default Site

```
server {
listen 443 default;
listen [::]:443 default;
server_name default-host.localhost;
include conf.d/include/force-ssl.conf; #no different comment uncomment
location / {
proxy_pass $scheme://192.168.100.37:443/;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header   Host $host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

}`
```